# Whats the difference between reference to an array and array as a parameters in functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, pass-by-reference, implicit-conversion

What is the difference between functions, which have reference to an array:

```
// reference to array
void f_(char (&t)[5]) {
    auto t2 = t;
}
```

and simply array:

```
// just array
void f__(char t[5]) {
    auto t2 = t;
}
```

as a parameters?

The calling code is:

```
char cArray[] = "TEST";
f_(cArray);
f__(cArray);

char (&rcArr)[5] = cArray;
f_(rcArr);
f__(rcArr);
```

In both cases **t2** is **char***, but in first function my VS2019 is showing that **t** inside function has type **char(&t)[]** and **t** inside second function has type **char***.

So after all, is there any practical difference between those functions?

Comment: Try to pass an array as argument to both your functions, and see the first one fail. (The second actually takes a pointer, not an array.)

Comment: I edited the question. Functions take exact sized arrays.

Comment: The second still takes a pointer; when there's no reference, the size is ignored.

Comment: The second does not, in fact, take an exact sized array. It takes a pointer. Try it!

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that contain two consecutive underscores (`f__`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: Two circumstances where you'll see a distinct difference between your functions.  (1) Try to pass an array of three `char` to both.  (2)  Pass a `char *` (not an array) to both.  In both these circumstances, the calling code will compile in one case and not with the other.    Another difference is to print `sizeof(t)` in both your functions - you'll see (assuming you pass an array of five `char` to call both) that they produce different output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a complete array type parameter as for example

```
void f( int ( &a )[N] );
```

and within the function you will know the number of elements in the passed array.

When the function is declared like

```
void f( int a[] );
```

then the compiler adjusts the function declaration like

```
void f( int *a );
```

and you are unable to determine the number of elements in the passed array. So you need to specify a second parameter like

```
void f( int *a, size_t n );
```

Also functions with a referenced array parameter type may be overloaded. For example these two declarations

```
void f( int ( &a )[] );
```

and

```
void f( int ( &a )[2] );
```

declare two different functions.

And functions with a referenced array parameter type may be called with a braced list (provided that the corresponding parameter has the qualifier const) like for example

```
f( { 1, 2, 3 } );
```

Here is a demonstration program

```
#include <iostream>

void f( const int ( &a )[] )
{
    std::cout << "void f( const int ( & )[] ) called.\n";
}

void f( const int ( &a )[2] )
{
    std::cout << "void f( const int ( & )[2] ) called.\n";
}

void f( const int a[] )
{
    std::cout << "void f( const int [] ) called.\n";
}


int main()
{
    f( { 1, 2, 3 } );
}
```

The program output is

```
void f( const int ( & )[] ) called.
```

Comment: thanks, but first example wont compile. you need to specify size_t parameter like that: template<size_t N> void f(int (&a)[N]) {};

Comment: @hgrev I did not mean a template function. I mean non-tempalte functions. N is some constant expression or an absence of it.

Comment: yes, i mean non-template function too, but it wont compile until you specify N

Comment: @hgrev It seems you are using an old compiler or a compiler that contains a bug. See my updated post. You can try the program at www.godbolt.org

Comment: then please can you explain how "and within the function you will know the number of elements in the passed array." if i don't specify N ?

Comment: @hgrev If the number of elements in the parameter is specified as for example void f( int ( &a )[10] ); then you will know the number.:) You can apply the operator sizeof to the parameter and you will get the exact size of the array. When the parameter has not a referenced type when even you will specify void f( int a[10] ); the compiler will adjust the function declaration like void f( int *a ); That is you will deal with a pointer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240238/discussion-between-hgrev-and-vlad-from-moscow).

Comment: @hgrev I am sorry but I am going to go to bed because in Moscow there is 11.30 p.m.:)

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot pass arrays by value (a C restriction that C++ inherits) any declaration of a parameter as an array will 'decay' into a pointer (losing its size).  So the declaration

```
void f__(char t[5])
```

is identical to

```
void f__(char *t)
```

Everything else follows from this -- within the body of `f__`, `t` has a pointer type, NOT an array type.  So any `auto` inferencing from it will be based on that pointer type.